# Dataframes and Pandas - Locating Occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a dataframe, where I got the following:

| Match | Team A | Team B | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brasil | Germany | Germany |
| 2 | Brasil | Germany | Brasil |
| 3 | France | Denmark | France |
| 4 | Denmark | France | Denmark |

My question is, how would I find how many times team A won the match. Same for Team B.

Using isin by taking Team A and Searching on winner has not been giving me clear results. I am fairly new to Python and Pandas, so I am short on ideas.

Comment: Added a solution, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're looking for...

Team A Win Count:

```
>>> df[df['Team A'].eq(df['Winner'])].shape[0]
3
```

Team B Win Count:

```
>>> df[df['Team B'].eq(df['Winner'])].shape[0]
1
```

Comment: I ended up going with this option:  (odi['Team 2']==odi['Winner']).sum()

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, is that what you're looking for?

```
df[df['Team A'] == df['Winner']].groupby('Team A').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

```
    Team A    count
0   Brasil    1
1   Denmark   1
2   France    1
```

```
df[df['Team B'] == df['Winner']].groupby('Team B').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

```
    Team B      count
0   Germany     1
```

Comment: A simpler way of getting the same results would be: `df[df['Team A'].eq(df['Winner'])][['Team A']].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')`

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
df.filter(like='Team').eq(df['Winner'], axis=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
Team A    3
Team B    1
dtype: int64
```